# Retrieving Facebook page's fan

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

Is it possible to retrieve facebook fans' list from a administrator of a facebook page ? (supposing I am using a facebook app authenticated by this administrator)

Answer (score 1):

No. Facebook does not give you access to a list of page fans through the API.

Comment: Thank you, it is quite clear :)